# do I need to create overlay for each microservice container app

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have around 20 container app and for each one I have `deployment.yaml` and now let's say I want to put different `replicas` for each one. What below image suggest that I need to match `metadata:name`.

Is this means I need to create 20 `overlay.yaml` each for one container app? Can I managed all app with SINGLE overlay file?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you need 20 overlays, if each should have unique config.

Comment: Yes. I have different configuration for each service like custom environment variables as well.

Comment: If I have 4 deployment environment then I will have 4*20 = 80 overlays. That's huge maintenance. Don't we have any centralize way with minimum overlay files?

Comment: Is replicas different for all 4 environments? If you can set a default that covers 3 then you only need 20 overlays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be resolved by using `patches`. You will be able to manage all deployments with one overlay file per environment where you can set explicitly number of replicas for each deployment.

---

**Here's a simplified example of it:**

I have two environments: `dev` and `stage`. Both have `kustomization.yaml` with `patches` for specific deploys and numbers of replicas (different for both envs).

`tree command:`

```
.
├── base
│   ├── app-1.yaml
│   ├── app-2.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays
    ├── dev
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── stage
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

Deployment - `app-1.yaml:` (2nd is almost identical, different name and image)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example-1
        image: example:1.0
```

Below a snippet from `overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../../base

patches:
  - patch: |-
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/replicas
        value: 2
    target:
      group: apps
      version: v1
      kind: Deployment
      name: example-1
  - patch: |-
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/replicas
        value: 3
    target:
      group: apps
      version: v1
      kind: Deployment
      name: example-2
```

Actual result:

```
$ kubectl kustomize overlays/dev
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: example:1.0
        name: example-1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-2
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: example:2.0
        name: example-2
```

---

**Useful links:**

- [Kustomize patches](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patches/)
- [Kustomize components](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/config_management/components/) (this one is not directly connected, but idea is common)

Comment: you're genius. Thanks for your reply. I have one interesting case, per microservice I have different sets of environment variable. Will `Path` helps here?

Comment: Here I asked another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295287/can-i-managed-using-single-overlay-per-environment-dev-test-qa-where-environme