# Kustomize: Can I managed using single overlay per environment (dev/test/qa) where environment variables for each microservice are different

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have different sets of `environment` variables per deployment/microservice and `vaule` for each environment (dev/test/qa) are different.

Do I need `overlay` file for each deployment/microservice against each environment (dev/test/qa) or I can managed with single overlay per environment?

Deployment - `app-1.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example-1
        image: example:1.0
        env:
          -Name: "A1"
          -Value: "B1"
        env:
          -Name: "D1"
          -Value: "E1"
```

Deployment - `app-2.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-2
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example-2
        image: example:2.0
        env:
          -Name: "X1"
          -Value: "Y1"
        env:
          -Name: "P1"
          -Value: "Q1"
```

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Do you use Helm, any CI/CD, or just kubectl apply?

Comment: @Emruz Hossain, just kubectl apply

Comment: Added an answer let me know whether it satisfies you requirements or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep everything inside the single YAML file and divide the YAML as per need.

you can use the `---` to merge the YAML configuration files in one file like the below in the example.

In a single YAML file, you can add everything Secret, deployment, service and etc as per requirement.

However if for each environment you have a different cluster to manage then applying the single YAML file might create the issues, in that case, it's better to keep the files separate.

If you are planning to set up the CI/CD and automation for deployment i would suggest keeping the single deployment file with a variable approach.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: DEPLOYMENT_NAME
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example-2
        image: IMAGE_NAME
        env:
          -Name: "A1"
          -Value: "B1"
```

using the ubuntu `sed` command you have to run time to replace the values of `IMAGE_NAME`, `DEPLOYMENT_NAME` and `A1` etc based on the environment and as soon as your file get ready you can apply from the CI/CD server

Single merged file :

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example-1
        image: example:1.0
        env:
          -Name: "A1"
          -Value: "B1"
        env:
          -Name: "D1"
          -Value: "E1"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-2
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example-2
        image: example:2.0
        env:
          -Name: "X1"
          -Value: "Y1"
        env:
          -Name: "P1"
          -Value: "Q1"
```

**EDIT**

If managing the environment is the only case you can also use the **secret** or **configmap** to manage the environment variables.

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dev-env-sample
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "sa-name"
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
data:
  extra: YmFyCg==
  A1 : B1
  D1 : E1
```

this is a single secret file storing all the Dev environment variables.

inject all variables to the Dev deployment, add the below config to the deployment file so all your variables inside that `config map` or `secret` will get injected into the deployment.

```
envFrom:
        - SecretRef:
            name: dev-env-sample
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

**configmap.yaml**

```
kind: ConfigMap 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: dev-configmap 
data:
  extra: YmFyCg==
  A1 : B1
  D1 : E1
```

and you can inject the configmap to deployment using the

```
envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: dev-configmap
```

The difference between **secret** and **configmap** is that secret save the data in **base64** encoded format while configmap save in plain text.

You can also merge the multiple `secrets` or `config map` in single YAML file

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: dev-env-sample
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "sa-name"
    type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
    data:
      extra: YmFyCg==
      A1 : B1
      D1 : E1
---
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: stag-env-sample
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "sa-name"
    type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
    data:
      extra: YmFyCg==
      A1 : B1
      D1 : E1
---
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: prod-env-sample
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "sa-name"
    type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
    data:
      extra: YmFyCg==
      A1 : B1
      D1 : E1
```

inject the **secret** into deployment as per need per environment.

`dev-env-sample` can be added in to the deployment file for **dev** environment.

Comment: Thanks Harsh. How to use single `configmap` to generate all microservices environment variables.? Could you please suggest some exact code, if possible?

Comment: I am using `kubectl apply` for now. No CI/CD

Comment: https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/ultimate-configmap-guide-kubernetes.html

Comment: Please visit above link it's easy guide also I have updated the question please check once also.

Comment: Using the secret & configmap is best practice to move with kubernets this way you can manage all your secret or environment variables from single YAML file

Comment: I agree on configmap (since in environment variable I don't have sensitive data), but still I am NOT clear how can I use with `Kustomize` context. plus in your sample code (single secret) file where is the placeholder where I am telling this sets of variables are for `exampe1` service and `  exampe2` service

Comment: for secret you can use the name to inject into the deployment `dev-env-sample`, `stag-env-sample` shared already code `envFrom: - SecretRef:` so all the variables inside that file or secret will be accessible to the service by KEY name you have set A1, D1 etc.

Comment: you didn't mention anything in question for kustomise : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kustomize/

Answer (score 2):

You can use variable in the env value field as below.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example-1
        image: example:1.0
        env:
        - Name: "A1"
          Value: ${A1_VALUE}
        - Name: "D1"
          Value: ${D1_VALUE}
```

Then, on `dev` env you can do the following.

```
export A1_VALUE=<your dev env value for A1>
export D1_VALUE=<your dev env value for D1>

envsubst < example-1.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Then, on `qa` env you can do the following.

```
export A1_VALUE=<your qa env value for A1>
export D1_VALUE=<your qa env value for D1>

envsubst < example-1.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

You can also put those env variables in a file. For example, you  can have the following two env files.

`dev.env` file

```
A1_VALUE=a1_dev
D1_VALUE=b1_dev
```

`qa.env` file

```
A1_VALUE=a1_qa
D1_VALUE=b1_qa
```

Then, on `dev` environment, just run:

```
❯ source dev.env
❯ envsubst < example-1.yaml| kubectl apply -f -
```

On `qa` environment, just run:

```
❯ source qa.env
❯ envsubst < example-1.yaml| kubectl apply -f -
```

> Note that you have to install `envsubst` in your machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question more on how to do with Kustomize. https://kustomize.io/

Comment: This post might help.
https://lundbird.medium.com/managing-kubernetes-environments-with-kustomize-ab3ab819d079